# How to get file path of a file inside a jar file?

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

**What's working**: I have a utility program that reads a bunch of groovy script files and executes them. If these groovy script files are placed outside the jar in the working directory then they are picked up and run as expected.

```
final class PluginBootStrapper  {
    private final GroovyScriptEngine scriptEngine = null
                
    private final List<Plugin> allPlugins = null;
    
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PluginBootStrapper.class)
    
    public PluginBootStrapper() 
    {
        String pluginsDir = System.getProperty(ABCProperties.endorsed_plugins_dir)
        scriptEngine = new GroovyScriptEngine(CommonUtils.getAllDirectories(
               pluginsDir))
        logger.info "Plugins Directory:"+System.getProperty(ABCProperties.endorsed_plugins_dir)
    
        allPlugins = loadDescriptor().invokeMethod("getAllPlugins",null)        
    }
    
    private Object loadDescriptor() {
        Object pluginDescriptor = bootStrapScript(abcProperties.get(abcProperties.PLUGIN_DESCRIPTOR))                                                                
        pluginDescriptor                         
    }
        
    Object bootStrapScript(String script) {
        Object pluginScript = scriptEngine.loadScriptByName(script)
                                          .newInstance()                                          
        pluginScript                                      
                                          
    }
    
    public List<Plugin> getAllPlugins()
    {
        return allPlugins
    }
}
```

**Issue**: Now I need to place these groovy scripts inside the jar file, I tried changing below statements inside `bootStrapScript` function

```
Object bootStrapScript(String script) {
    String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(script).toExternalForm()
    logger.info "bootStrapScript script "+ path
    Object pluginScript = scriptEngine.loadScriptByName(script)
                                      .newInstance()                                          
    pluginScript                                      
                                      
}
```

but it is unable to find the groovy scripts and throws below exception (screenshot for the jar content is attached below, even tried placing all the scripts file inside plugins folder)

[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.util.ResourceException: No resource for Plugins.groovy was found
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.getResourceConnection(GroovyScriptEngine.java:421)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.loadScriptByName(GroovyScriptEngine.java:558)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine$loadScriptByName.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at com.jagra.abc.plugins.PluginBootStrapper.bootStrapScript(PluginBootStrapper.groovy:42)
    at com.jagra.abc.plugins.PluginBootStrapper$bootStrapScript.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at com.jagra.abc.plugins.PluginBootStrapper.loadDescriptor(PluginBootStrapper.groovy:33)
    at com.jagra.abc.plugins.PluginBootStrapper.<init>(PluginBootStrapper.groovy:28)
    at com.jagra.abc.abc.run(abc.java:65)
    at com.jagra.abc.abcMain.main(abcMain.java:15)
```

Note: Here is `pluginsDir` is `.\plugins`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such thing as a file path to a resource in a jar file, because the resource is not a file.

When the 'file' is in a jar file, you'll need to load it as a resource, not as file, so something like getResourceAsStream().

The commonality between loading a file and loading a non-file resource is that they can both be loaded as streams.

So, I can think of two solutions:

A: Change your script loader to support files and resources, loading each differently.

or

B: Change your script loader to always read a stream, and provide the functionality outside of the loader to load a file or a resource, and provide the resulting stream to the script loader.